# deleting allocated two d array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am trying to allocate two-D array at runtime. Size of the array is N*N where N is input by the user.
In the end I am deleting the allocated memory. But I am getting Segmentation Fault.
I know that Segmentation fault occurs when I try to access  memory not allocated by me. Please Help Code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int t,n;
    int **judge;
    int **result;
    int i,j,l;
    int high;
    float count;
    int item;
    cin>>t;
    while(t-->0)
    {
        cin>>n;
        judge=new int*[n];result=new int*[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            judge[i]=new int[n];
            result[i]=new int[n];
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                cin>>judge[i][j];
            }
        }
        count=0;
        result[0][0]=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                item=0;
                if(j>0&&i>0)
                {
                if(item<result[i][j-1])
                    item=result[i][j-1];
                else if(item<result[i-1][j])
                    item=result[i-1][j];
                }
                else if(i==0)
                {
                    if(item<result[i][j-1])
                        item=result[i][j-1];
                }
                else if(j==0)
                {
                    if(item<result[i-1][j])
                        item=result[i-1][j];
                }

                result[i][j]=judge[i][j]+item;
            }
        }

        if(result[n-1][n-1]<0.0)
            cout<<"Bad Judges"<<endl;
        else
        {
            count=(result[n-1][n-1]/(float)n);
            cout<<count<<endl;
        }

        for( i = 0 ; i < n  ; ++i)
        {
            delete[] result[i] ;
        }
        delete[] result;
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
        {
            delete[] judge[i] ;
        }
        delete[] judge;
        /* for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            delete[] judge[i];
            delete[] result[i];       
        }*/
        // delete[] judge;
        //delete[] result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: My advice to you about 2d arrays is: Don't! Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. E.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>> judge;`

Comment: 1) Before you posted this, you should have *simplified* it, cut out the interaction, the `item` calculation, reduced it to 1D, basically removed as much as you could while preserving the error; that would have made our job easier. 2) You should have written it that way, building up from the simple to the complex, testing at every step; that would have made your job easier.

Comment: Your arrays are all size n. We should only ever be seeing 0 and < n appearing. All these n+1s n+2s n-1s are obviously wrong. What are you thinking here? You know arrays size n run from 0 .. n-1?

Comment: Yes I know @TheMathemagician Kindly recheck the code sir...!!

Comment: @ Whoever voted down, Please give me one reason you vote it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop `judge` till `n+2` and you do not allocate that much.

In those three lines:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 2 ; ++i)
{
   delete[] judge[i] ;
}
```

By the way this is not the only time you access memory you have not allocated:

```
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
{
   for(j=1;j<n+1;j++)
   {
     cin>>judge[i][j];
   }
}
```

Here `i` and `j` might reach up to `n`, whilst your allocation allows for values up to `n -1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of loops like

```
for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
```

In C++, arrays are indexed from 0 so you should use [0..n) instead

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Comment: Funny thing is some of the loops are correct. There is a curious mix in this code.

Comment: @Gorpik I think the OP needed to allocate some more of the `judge` variable

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I don't really know what he wants to do here. Now he has silently modified his code, but we don't know whether there was some transcription error in the original, he has fixed his problem or what happens.

Comment: @Gorpik there was some error in the original. I accidently copied wrong file. But this current code also gives same error.

Comment: @MohitSehgal You are still accessing illegal positions. Every time you run the `while` loop, inside the third `for` loop, when `i == 0` and `j == 0` you try to access `result[0][-1]`.

Comment: @Gorpik Agreed that code is wrong but he's only reading from these locations so they shouldn't (directly) cause a seg fault while deleting the arrays.

Comment: @MohitSehgal Can you confirm whether your code still fails trying to delete its arrays?  Or is it now failing at the line Gorpik flagged?

Comment: @downvoter Can you explain what the problem is with this answer?  (Other than that it is no longer obviously valid since the OP updated his question to fix the errors highlighted.)